# TableView no longer loading but was before

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

Keep running into this error:
2017-04-28 11:58:06.873 Fixee[97466:2668136] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:heightCanBeGuessed:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UITableViewRowData.m:1846

It was working, but now is crashing talking about row heights, but i do return the same values as I have. Can anyone see the issue? I have two tableviews but one is called hireTableView, and the other .is tableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(tableView == self.tableView){
        let cell  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for : indexPath) as! CustomCell


        let bgColorView = UIView()


        //bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.withAlphaComponent(0.15)
        //bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView



        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
        {
            if(indexPath.row == 0){

                cell.profileTitleLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getTitle()
                if(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].status == 0){
                    cell.profileStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                }
                else{
                    cell.profileStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 28/255.0, green: 121/255.0, blue: 125/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                }
                cell.profileStatusLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].calculateSolved())"
                cell.profileMessageCountLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].commentCount)"

                cell.profileProblemImage.image =  problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getImage()

                cell.profileUpdateLabel.text = "Last Update: 13:01   25/01/2017"

                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


            }
            else{

                cell.profileTitleLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].getTitle()
                if(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].status == 0){
                    cell.profileStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                }
                else{
                    cell.profileStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 28/255.0, green: 121/255.0, blue: 125/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                }
                cell.profileStatusLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].calculateSolved())"
                cell.profileMessageCountLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].commentCount)"
                cell.profileProblemImage.image = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].getImage()

                cell.profileUpdateLabel.text = "Last Update: 13:01   25/01/2017"

                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


            }
        }
        else{

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            cell.profileTitleLabel.text = ""
            cell.profileStatusLabel.text = ""
            cell.profileMessageCountLabel.text = ""

            cell.profileProblemImage.image = nil
            cell.profileUpdateLabel.text = ""
            cell.selectionStyle = .none


        }
        return cell

    }
    else{

        let cell  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for : indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.seperator.isHidden = true
        cell.bubble.isHidden = true

        let bgColorView = UIView()

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
        {
            if(indexPath.row == 0){

                cell.profileTitleLabel.text = ""
                cell.profileStatusLabel.text = ""
                cell.profileMessageCountLabel.text = ""

                cell.profileProblemImage.image = nil
                cell.profileUpdateLabel.text = ""

                cell.textLabel?.text = hires[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].title
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(hires[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].price)"


            }
            else{

                cell.profileTitleLabel.text = ""
                cell.profileStatusLabel.text = ""
                cell.profileMessageCountLabel.text = ""

                cell.profileProblemImage.image = nil
                cell.profileUpdateLabel.text = ""

                cell.textLabel?.text = hires[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].title
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(hires[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].price)"
            }
        }
        else{

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            cell.textLabel?.text = ""
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.profileTitleLabel.text = ""
            cell.profileStatusLabel.text = ""
            cell.profileMessageCountLabel.text = ""

            cell.profileProblemImage.image = nil
            cell.profileUpdateLabel.text = ""

        }


        return cell


    }




}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    var height: CGFloat = 0

    if tableView == self.tableView {
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
        {
            height = 70 //cell height
        }
        else
        {
            height = 5 //space heigh
        }
    }

    if tableView == self.hireTableView {
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
        {
            height = 60 //cell height
        }
        else{
            height = 5 //space heigh
        }

    }


    return height
}
```

Comment: replacing your line with this :         let cell  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomCell or use **different identifier** for both cell

Comment: thank you, replacing the line is what fixed it!! Cheers KKRocks!

Comment: cool ! Welcome @haydg8

Comment: can i add this as my answer ?

Comment: Please do! That was my first question, just been googling how to up vote your comment and mark it as the answer haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your code

1. Replacing your line with this :

   let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomCell
2. Use different identifier for both cell .